# .Net 6.0 Core How Can pass IHttpContextAccessor to as Dependency Injection parameter in Program.cs

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using Asp.Net Core 6.0 Web MVC Application. I have a static extension method which listening to RabbitMQ. In the **Program.cs**, I am trying to pass **IHttpContextAccessor** as Dependency Injection parameter to **app.UseRabbitListener()** extension method like below code: (But i cant.)

```
app.UseRabbitListener(RabbitMqConstants.KEYSTR_FrontEnd_1, 
    new RabbitMq_RunThisAction(
          app.Services.GetService<RabbitMqClass>(), 
          new SignalRClass(app.Services.GetService<ChatHub>()),
          new SignalR_SessionClass(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>())
    )
);
```

I will use Session values in **SignalR_SessionClass()** but i  cant get **accessor.HttpContext** in   constructor of class.  It came as null.

I also tried this ways in Program.cs but i failed :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpContextAccessor>();
var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var accessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();//accessor.HttpContext is null
var accessor2 = serviceProvider.GetService<HttpContextAccessor>();//accessor.HttpContext is null
var accessor3 = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();//accessor.HttpContext is null
var accessor4 = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpContextAccessor>();//accessor.HttpContext is null
```

How can I pass **IHttpContextAccessor** to static extension metod?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register `IHttpContextAccessor` with the `AddHttpContextAccessor` method in `Program.cs`. However, you can't resolve `HttpContextAccessor` at startup, because there will be no request for `HttpContext`. In your case, it's better to change `SignalR_SessionClass` dependencies to `IServiceProvider` and then resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` whenever you want it.